# Querying from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Basically I am trying to display 3 users, I am querying from the _User class the following: username, profilePicture & Name.

After that I would like to query the last photo they posted from the Posts class.

Here is how I have  setup my code :

```
        let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        userQuery.limit = 3
        userQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.profilePicArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.fullnameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {

                    self.profilePicArray.append(object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                    self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
                    self.fullnameArray.append(object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String)
                    self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
                }

                let imageQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                imageQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.usernameArray)
                imageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.lastPicArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        for object in objects! {
                            self.lastPicArray.append(object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                        }
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                    } else {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

But when I run it, it isn't showing the correct image for the user showing...I cannot get my head round it, it's been driving me mad for several hours now!!

Comment: BTW, parse will retire next year, unless you have your own server running parse server.

Comment: @antonio081014 ye, I know thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It might cause by data transferring in different time cost since you use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. Threads running in background are hard to control. So the order of images in `imageQuery` `objects` is different with `usernameArray`. Or `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` doesn't guarantee that data will be fetched in same order with keys set. Not 100% sure about this.

But try putting the image fetching procedure inside the first `for object in objects!` loop. It might be able to solve your problem.

For sorting answer from creeperspeak, you should be able to get username back  from `imageQuery` class just like `object.valueForKey("username")` in your first loop. Then match them with `self.usernameArray`.

Comment: Hey, I have managed to get the images from the users and display them  and everything else. But what I need to do now is re order the images so they're the correct ones for each user. At the moment their all randomly placed! do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The background thread isn't a problem for fetching your images, but your image query is not set to return images in any specific order, nor does it seem to limit how many photos will come back for each user (unless you have it set up so that the Post object can only hold one post per user).  You could handle this in a few different ways, but the easiest way might be to sort your object array in some predictable order, using the username as the sort key, and then when you get your images back you can sort them in the same order based on their username property before putting them into the array that drives the collectionView.

One other note - you'll want to put your `.reloadData()` call back on the main thread or it'll happen at an unpredictable time.

Comment: Hi, I have just 1 image, and I only want it to show the latest 1 the user posted. I am trying to match the username from the _User class to the username in the Posts class, and then order it by the latest posted.. so what would you say I should do? In the imageQuery as you can see what I'm trying to do is match the usernam containedIn the usernameArray..?!